# Расчёт суммы элементов в javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, linq

Есть денежный перевод на сумму moneyTransfer.Amount, на этот перевод может быть создано несколько transactionCategory (коды бюджета), у каждой категории своя сумма .Amount

Типа, купили в перекрёстке на 1000 рублей по чеку, в нём 900 рублей продукты, а 100 - хозтовары.

В шарпе если мне нужно посчитать вся ли сумма классифицирована, я пишу что-то типа:

```
var isCategorized = Math.Abs(Model.Transaction.Transaction.Amount - Model.Transaction.Categories.Sum(x => x.Amount)) < 0.01m;
```

Когда я полез писать это же условие, то на нативном js как-то многословно выходило, потом я взял из lodash _.sum и вышло что-то типа:

```
hasCategorised(info) {
    var categoriesAmount = _.sumBy(info.categories, "amount");
    return Math.abs(info.transaction.amount - categoriesAmount) < 0.01;
}
```

В итоге вздохнул и унёс расчёт на бекенд.

А вообще, как это сделать на javascript если нет lodash? Какой вариант правильный? Смотрел в сторону [reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1230233/5752652), но почему-то не зашло.

Comment: [В указанном вами топике в принятом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751601/6766879) в версии для ES6 есть толстый намек как это можно сделать: `var categoriesAmount = info.categories.reduce((acc, cat) => acc + cat.amount);`